# Show that $T=T'$, the topologies induced by metrics $d$ and $d'$, respectively.

Tags: general-topology

According to the book:

[image]
[image]

Is it easy to see that if we suppose $\epsilon\le 1$ thus $d(x,y)=d'(x,y)$ thus $B_d(x,\epsilon)=B_d'(x,\delta)$. But how can it be possible that $B_d(x,\epsilon)\subset B_d'(x,\delta)$ if $\epsilon> 1$? I mean, if $\epsilon> 1$ then $d(x,y)> 1$ and $d'(x,y)=1$, which will result in $B_d'(x,1)\subset B_d(x,\epsilon)$; which means $T$ is always finer $T'$. It is also apparent for especial case of standard topology: any open set in finite interval is also open set in $\mathbb{R}$, but any open set in $\mathbb{R}$ may not be even subset of some fixed finite interval. So $T$ and $T'$ are not equal, contrary to the statement of the book. Please guide me how this is.

Thank you.

Comment: It is correct that $T$ is finer than $T'$. At the same time $T'$ is finer than $T$. So what do we conclude?

Comment: Yes, but only if $\epsilon\le 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked:

> But how can it be possible that $B_d(x,\epsilon)\subset B_d'(x,\delta)$ if $\epsilon> 1$?

That inclusion does not hold. You switched $\epsilon$ and $\delta$.

For the troublesome direction, remember that we are allowed to choose $\delta$ *smaller* than the given $\epsilon$. If $\epsilon>1$ we choose $\delta=1$. That is what is meant by

$$\delta=\min\{\epsilon,1\}.$$

We choose $\delta$ so small that the $\delta$-ball is contained in the $\epsilon$-ball. Not the other way around.